# Problema para guardar una foto en la base de datos

Tags: php, imagen

Quiero guardar una foto en la base de datos pero estoy teniendo un problema muy extraño. Cuando pulso el botón para guardar la imagen en la base de datos esta se esta guardado en la carpeta de mi servidor **"img-profile"** se supone que esta esta pasando el filtro, pero no se guarda el nombre y la extension en la BD y he creado un `var_dump` para ver si me esta llegando algo por **$_FILES[]** y dice que no me esta llegando nada pero esta pasando el filtro que le programado, porque la imagen llega correctamente a la carpeta `img-profile` y se guarda con su nombre y extensión pero no se guarda en la BD porque por el `var_dump` no esta llegando nada.

**Formulario HTML5:**

```
 <!-- Modal Structure -->
 <div id="photo-complete" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="flow-text pink-text center">Coloca una foto de perfil</h4>
      
        <form action="./backend/photo-profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn btn-color">
                <span><i class="material-icons">photo_camera</i></span>
                <input type="file" name="photo" required>
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input class="file-path validate" name="photo" type="text" placeholder="Selecciona una foto de perfil">
            </div>
            </div>

              <button class="btn waves-effect right btn-color" type="submit" name="submit">enviar
                <i class="material-icons left">send</i>
              </button><br><br><br>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Logica PHP:**

```
<?php session_start();
require('../connection/connection.php');
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
require('../user/user.php');

$errors = '';

if(isset($_FILES['photo'])){

    $photo = $_FILES['photo'];
    var_dump($photo);

    // Verificar que nos llegue la imagen
    if(empty($photo)){
        $errors = 'Selecciona una imagen';
    }

    $photoName = $photo['name'];
    $photoType = $photo['type'];

     // Asegurarnos que la imagen contenga un formato de img
     if($photoType == "image/jpg" || $photoType == "image/png" || $photoType == "image/jpeg" || $photoType == "image/git" || $photoType == "image/gif" || $photoType == ""){

        // Verificar el peso de la imagen
        if($photo['size'] >= $maxSize) {
            $errors .= 'La imagen pesa mucho, por favor solo 2MB';
        }

        if(!is_dir('../img-profile')){
            mkdir('../img-profile', 0777);
        }

        // Movemos la img a la carpeta photo
        move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'], '../img-profile/'.$photoName);

    }else {
        $errors .= "Lo siento, no aceptamos esta extension $photoName";
    }

    // No hay problemas y pasa por nuestro filtro, dejalo registrar el producto
    if($errors == ''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE users SET photo_profile = '$photoName' WHERE id_user = $id_user"
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':photoName' => $photoName,
            ':id_user' => $id_user

        ));

        header('Location: ./photo-cover');
    }else{
        header('Location: ./photo-profile');
    }

    var_dump($errors);

}else{
    echo 'No llega nada';
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el `prepare()` debes usar `:` en lugar de `$`, y sin comillas simples el valor para `photo_profile`.

Comment: El problema no esta en la conexion, si no en que no me esta llegando nada cuando debería de estar llegándome algo ya que los datos están correcto. Si ves en la imagen dice que no me esta llegando nada

Comment: Con `header('Location: ./photo-profile')` estas volviendo a cargar el mismo php, pero ahora sin archivos; y por eso "No llega nada".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al no estar definida `$maxSize`, se evalúa que el tamaño del archivo es mayor a cero y se agrega el error a `$errors`.

Al no cumplirse `$errors == ''`, se recarga el mismo php con `header('Location: ./photo-profile')` pero ahora sin archivos, resultando en el mensaje "No llega nada".